# Empty authorDisplayName requesting youtube video comment

Tags: youtube-data-api

Some comments are being returned through the `commentThreads` endpoint with an empty `authorDisplayName` field. Accessing directly on the youtube the same comment is shown without the author's name and it's impossible to access the author's channel.

I have noticed that after a few hours some comments started to return correctly, without any clearly reason. And immediately after that the API starts to return correctly too. Does anyone know why it happened?

[image: Comment example without user information]

Comment: Could well have been a transient error somewhere within Google's implementation. You may inquire further by posting a question on Google's own [issue tracker site](https://issuetracker.google.com/).